# How to clear all notifications?

Tags: notifications

When there are some notifications on the screen, I can't click on the Clear All Notifications button (because they appear on top of this button). How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good point! You should definitely report this UI design flaw to elementary OS developers @ https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel-indicator-notifications

Comment: Good idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One hacky way to do it would be to run `killall wingpanel`
and then `wingpanel &`